# I am trying to migrate my model - but it's giving me error -

Tags: python, django

Error - client.Client.status: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.

Here is the code:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ACTIVE = 'AC',
    TO_EXPIRE = 'TE',
    EXPIRED = 'EX',
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (TO_EXPIRE, 'To Expire'),
        (EXPIRED, 'Expired'),

    ]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=ACTIVE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: please add your objective, what are you trying to do with your program.

Comment: I am trying to ask the user to input the client name, address, start date, start end, then save. Once save the status in the db will be Active.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is simple, but subtle:

```
ACTIVE = 'AC',
TO_EXPIRE = 'TE',
EXPIRED = 'EX',
```

You must remove the trailing commas here. Python interprets these as tuples of length one with the 0 index value equal to the string.

eg

```
ACTIVE = ('AC',) 
# is equivalent to
ACTIVE = 'AC',
```

What you want here is simply `ACTIVE = 'AC'`

Comment: Hi smassey, thanks for the input! I was able to migrate now.

Comment: Hi @GilbertGetuya nice, it's always nice to hear back ;)

Comment: @GilbertGetuya this should be an accepted answer :)